# how to run a bash script with multiple lines on crontab

Tags: cron

Because vpnc stopped every ~23 hours, I created a .sh file that is running as a cron job every 10 minutes, all that it does, is stop the vpnc process and run it again.

I have made it executable by `chmod + x ping_vpnc.sh` and it works fine when I run it from the terminal via `./ping_vpnc.sh`

My file looks similar to:

```
#!/bin/sh

killall vpnc #just to make sure I don't create too many tunnels.
vpnc default.conf  #run vpnc connect file.
```

my crontab file:

```
*/10 * * * * /home/username/ping_vpnc.sh
```

the problem with the script that it does't run fully, so it just kill the process without re-running it.

I'm running the script as root so I don't think that it's a privilege issue.

Any idea about why this is happening? I will appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not extremely familiar with `vpnc`, but could it be the case that the old process takes a little time to die fully, and the new one notices that the old one is still (partially) there, so it refuses to start? Maybe put a `sleep 1` in between the two or something if that's the case...

Comment: I tried it but it still the same issue, and wehn I run the bash script manually ./ping_vpnc.sh it works as expected! but not on crontab :(

Comment: Change `* * * ... /home...` for `* * * /bin/sh /home...`, you need to indicate the binary executing the script.

Comment: I made the change and I have to wait few minutes so the script can run on crontab. your solution seems right and I found something similar here but I didn't understand it until your suggested the solution. `http://askubuntu.com/questions/117978/script-doesnt-run-via-crontab-but-works-fine-standalone/277869#277869`  Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: please put your suggestion as solution, it works perfect!!! thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated on comments, change

```
*/10 * * * * /home/username/ping_vpnc.sh
```

for

```
*/10 * * * * /bin/sh /home/username/ping_vpnc.sh
```

that is, tell crontab which binary has to execute the script.

For future references, let me point out the question you found in Ask Ubuntu: [Script doesn't run via crontab but works fine standalone](https://askubuntu.com/q/117978/143251). It provides comprehensive information about the topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to put this together!! I highly appreciate it!!